# Can't add a admin role to my admin account

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a Grails 3.3.0 web interface for my internship with PostgreSQL version 10 as database and spring-security-core version 3.2.0.

Every time i start the project i can login with my admin account but i can not view a page.

Also when i view the spring-security-core-ui i see that i logged in as admin, but i do not have the role "ROLE_ADMIN" but when i give it and save i get a error "No such property: transactionStatus for class: grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService"

This is the text that i see on the page:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI: /user/update (the same with /user/save)
Coused by: No such property: transactionStatus for class: grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService
Trace:

Line | Method
->>  211 | invoke           in org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    188 | invoke           in org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass
|     90 | handle . . . . . in org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter
|    967 | doDispatch       in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
|    901 | doService . . .  in     ''
|    970 | processRequest   in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    872 | doPost . . . . . in     ''
|    846 | service          in     ''
|     55 | doFilterInternal in org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter
|    317 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    127 | invoke . . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
|     91 | doFilter         in     ''
|    331 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    114 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter
|     64 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     54 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    158 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    170 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    200 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     64 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    105 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     58 | doFilter . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    214 | doFilterInternal in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
|    177 | doFilter         in     ''
|     77 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
|     67 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
|   1149 | runWorker . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread

Caused by MissingPropertyException: No such property: transactionStatus for class: grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService
->>  344 | addRoles         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    324 | $tt__updateUser  in     ''
|     94 | doInTransaction  in grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
|    133 | execute          in org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate
|     91 | execute . . . .  in grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate
|     33 | updateUser       in grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.DefaultUserStrategy
|     41 | doCall . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.UserController$_update_closure1
|     86 | doUpdate         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.AbstractS2UiDomainController
|     40 | update . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.UserController
|    211 | invoke           in org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker
|    188 | invoke . . . . . in org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass
|     90 | handle           in org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter
|    967 | doDispatch . . . in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
|    901 | doService        in     ''
|    970 | processRequest . in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    872 | doPost           in     ''
|    846 | service . . . .  in     ''
|     55 | doFilterInternal in org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter
|    317 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    127 | invoke           in org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
|     91 | doFilter . . . . in     ''
|    331 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    114 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter
|     64 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter
|    331 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     54 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    331 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    158 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
|    331 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    170 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
|    331 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    200 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
|    331 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     64 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|    331 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    105 | doFilter         in org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
|    331 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     58 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter
|    331 | doFilter . . . . in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    214 | doFilterInternal in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
|    177 | doFilter . . . . in     ''
|     77 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
|     67 | doFilterInternal in org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
|   1149 | runWorker        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run              in java.lang.Thread
```

The code of my project can be found at github: https://github.com/rm93/Grails_web_interface

Does anyone now what goes wrong?

Comment: please specify error message or code fragment related to your question.

Comment: @akhambir i updated my post.

Comment: did you put in "permission" with url map in application.groovy?

Comment: Yes i have. I have made a new project and now it works. So I think I have taken something away in the spring security ui which was not the intention. So this topic can be closed.